# My program is saying 'p1_move1' is not defined

Tags: python

I have no idea why this is not working, it says the p1_move1 is not defined but it is at the top.

```
import random
p1_move1 = '0'
p1_move2 = '0'
p1_move3 = '0'
p1_move4 = '0'
player1pokemonchoice = '1'
player1pokemonhealth = 1000
cpupokemonhealth = 1000

if player1pokemonchoice == '1':
    print ('''ATTACKS:
 1. RKO - Damage 100 - 200
 2. NATURE SLAM - Damage 100 - 200
 3. GREEN ATTACK - Damage 100 - 200
 4. NATURE GROTH - Damage 100 - 200''')
 while player1pokemonchoice == '1' and player1pokemonhealth>=0 and cpupokemonhealth>=0:
p1_move = int(input('Which move would you like to choose?'))
if p1_move == 1:
    p1_move1 = random.randint(100, 200)
    cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - pl_move1
    print (p1_move1, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
elif p1_move == 2:
    p1_move2 = random.randint(100, 200)
    cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - pl_move2
    print (p1_move2, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
elif p1_move == 3:
    p1_move3 = random.randint(100, 200)
    cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - pl_move3
    print (p1_move3, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
elif p1_move == 4:
    p1_move4 = random.randint(100, 200)
    cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - pl_move4
    print (p1_move4, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
```

Comment: *Where* is it saying `p1_move1` isn't defined? Which line? There are three separate places where the error could be being raised, and where the error is might help answer the question.

Comment: This is a simple typo, confusing `l` with `1` and should therefore be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each subtraction line in your `while` loop, the `p1_move1 (or 2 or 3 or 4)` actually says pl (That's an "L", not a 1)

Comment: i have to wait 23 more seconds

Answer (score 0):

You put integers between commas and there were some typo mistakes instead of p1 you typed pl. So try this one

```
import random
p1_move1 = 0
p1_move2 = 0
p1_move3 = 0
p1_move4 = 0
player1pokemonchoice = 1
player1pokemonhealth = 1000
cpupokemonhealth = 1000

if player1pokemonchoice == 1:
  print ('''ATTACKS:
  1. RKO - Damage 100 - 200
  2. NATURE SLAM - Damage 100 - 200
  3. GREEN ATTACK - Damage 100 - 200
  4. NATURE GROTH - Damage 100 - 200''')
  while player1pokemonchoice == 1 and player1pokemonhealth>=0 and 
  cpupokemonhealth>=0:
      p1_move = int(raw_input('Which move would you like to choose?'))
      if p1_move == 1:
         p1_move1 = random.randint(100, 200)
         cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - p1_move1
         print (p1_move1, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
      elif p1_move == 2:
        p1_move2 = random.randint(100, 200)
        cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - p1_move2
        print (p1_move2, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
     elif p1_move == 3:
        p1_move3 = random.randint(100, 200)
        cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - p1_move3
        print (p1_move3, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
     elif p1_move == 4:
        p1_move4 = random.randint(100, 200)
        cpupokemonhealth = cpupokemonhealth - p1_move4
        print (p1_move4, "was dealt to the CPU's pokemon. His health is", cpupokemonhealth)
```

Comment: Umm... please don't repeat answers, it takes the credit away from the original answerer. If I missed something, (in this case, I see you wanted to provide the code to copy and paste), you can just leave a comment. Thanks!

Comment: I did not repeat the answer, I was finalizing while you sent it that was the reason I did not see your reply. By the way I believe if your score is under a certain point you can not leave only comment but have to answer the question

Comment: Ok, that's fine, just there is a reputation reward for having your answer accepted, and not to sound greedy, but I kinda want it (if I deserve it). And yah, I see your reputation, and yah, I know how that feels, just that sometimes, you shouldn't try to replace comments with answers (I was scolded for it :).

Comment: Dear Levi, I fully understand you that you want to increase your reputation, but before requesting 'accepted' mark from your interlocutor, at least you should be sure that your recommended way runs the code. Anyways this platform is not an arena to fight between us but a platform to help each others on our long way.